# Wordpress non-primary menu not appearing in GraphQL

Tags: wordpress, graphql

I am trying to insert a non-primary menu into my Gatsby site using GraphQL.
I am following this documentation [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/docs/tutorials/using-wordpress-menus.md#:%7E:text=Query%20a%20Menu%20by%20Location%20and%20it%27s%20MenuItems,label%20title%20path%20parentId%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D)

I created a menu called 'Steve-Menu'
I have registered the menu in functions.php like so:

```php
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'register_gcd_menu');
function register_gcd_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('Steve-Menu', 'Geo Code Design');
}
```

In my admin the new location "Geo Code Design" is available. I check the box to assign it a location. Should be active, right?

I use the following GraphQL query in GraphiQL

```
{
  wpMenu(locations: {ne: PRIMARY}) {
    menuItems {
      nodes {
        id
        title
        uri
      }
    }
    locations
  }
}
```

I get null. I was expecting to see the other menu.
I think the problem is that the location isn't appearing as an enum. The only location listed in the GraphiQL autofill is the enum PRIMARY. Is this a problem?